# Why "OneToOne" relationship allow to store more than one data in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working on `OneToOne` relationship with Spring MVC. In my code `Person` is parent table and `Address` is child table. I'm persist data in `Person` table after that in `Address` table. I put `list of person` dropdown in address page, List of person dropdown take reference while persist data in child table(Address). I have no problem while persist data into both table but problem is child table insert more than one data with same foreign key in `Address` table but, I declare `OneToOne` Relationship Mapping, so, Why Hibernate does not produce error while store more than one data in `Address` table.

Here down is my code:

**Entity**

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long p_id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private Address address;

    // getter setter
}
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long a_id;

    private String district;
    private String city;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Person.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_id")
    private Person person;

    // getter setter
}
```

**Controller**

```
// add person in database
@RequestMapping(value = "/addperson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPerson(Model mdl, @ModelAttribute("persons") Person person)
{
    pojoService.addPerson(person);
    return "redirect:/persons";
}

// add address in database
@RequestMapping(value = "/addaddress", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAddress(Model mdl, @ModelAttribute("address") Address address)
{
    pojoService.addAddress(address);
    return "redirect:/address";
}
```

**addperson(Thymeleaf)**

```
<form th:action="@{/addperson}" th:object="${person}" method="post">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 style="text-align: center">Add Person</h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Person name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" th:field="*{name}">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Person surname</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" th:field="*{surname}">
                </div>
                
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
                
                <br>
                <a th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**addaddress(Thymeleaf)**

```
<form th:action="@{/addaddress}" th:object="${address}" method="post">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 style="text-align: center">Add Address</h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Student Name</label>
                  <select th:field="*{person}" class="form-select" aria-label=".Default select example">
                    <th:block th:each="personList: ${person}">
                        <option th:text="${personList.name + ' ' + personList.surname}" th:value="${personList.p_id}"></option>
                    </th:block>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">District</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{district}">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">City</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{city}">
                </div>
                
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
                
                <br>
                <a th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Result**

Person table:

[image]

Address Table:

[image]

Here down i would show you how my `add person` and `add address` page look:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring Framwork, we always have to take reference to store foreign key in child table. In your case, you can't take any reference while store data in child table. You have to take reference of parent table primary key then, insert data in child table. it can check if data is already exist in record then, data is updated in record otherwise insert new data in record.

**How to take reference before insert child table?**

```
// add person in database
@RequestMapping(value = "/addperson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPerson(Model mdl, @ModelAttribute("persons") Person person)
{
    pojoService.addPerson(person);
    return "redirect:/persons";
}

// add address in database
@RequestMapping(value = "/addaddress", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAddress(Model mdl, @ModelAttribute("address") Address address)
{
    Person person = address.getPerson();
    person.setAddress(address); 
    pojoService.addAddress(address);
    return "redirect:/address";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Person` class inside `oneToOne` mapping put `orphanRemoval="true"`
Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: You require to change your implementation, in your controller class where you are saving address, you need to save the parent entity rather than the child entity, ie in your case you need to save the `person`object. Your implementation should be something like Person person =pojoService.get(address.getPerson()): person.setAddress(address); pojoService.addPerson();

Comment: You are facing this issue because you are first saving the `person` object then you are saving the `address` object. Both entities are having `oneToOne` realation. So, I suggest that rather than saving `address` entity. You should update the `Person` entity with `address` object